# SQL Load Fact with Merge Statement Slow

Tags: sql

I'm loading a fact table using `MERGE` and it's taking 44 minutes for 1 million records. Is there a way I can improve this?

My query:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.FactProjMarketCode AS target

USING (
    SELECT 
        SourceSystem = 'ORACLE_ERP',
        ProjMarketCodeSourceId = jmc.XT_JOB_MARKETING_CODE_ID,
        p.ProjectId,
        MarketCodeId = ISNULL(mc.MarketingCodeId,-1), 
        Weight = 0.01 * ISNULL(jmc.WEIGHT,100),
        WasMissing = CASE WHEN jmc.WEIGHT IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        jmc.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
    FROM 
        dimProject p
        LEFT JOIN stage.XT_JOB_MARKETING_CODE jmc
            ON p.ProjectSourceId = jmc.XT_PROJECT_ID 
        LEFT JOIN DimMarketingCode mc
            ON jmc.MARKETING_CODE = mc.MarketingCode -- should create column MarketingCodeSourceId
            AND mc.SourceSystem = 'ORACLE_ERP'
    WHERE
        p.SourceSystem = 'ORACLE_ERP'
) AS source 
    ON target.SourceSystem = source.SourceSystem
    AND target.ProjMarketCodeSourceId = source.ProjMarketCodeSourceId
WHEN MATCHED AND source.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > target.LAST_UPDATE_DATE 
THEN UPDATE SET
  target.ProjectId = source.ProjectId,
  target.MarketCodeId = source.MarketCodeId,
  target.Weight = source.WEIGHT,
  target.WasMissing = source.WasMissing,
  target.LAST_UPDATE_DATE = source.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target 
THEN INSERT (
  SourceSystem,
  ProjMarketCodeSourceId,
  ProjectId,
  MarketCodeId,
  Weight,
  WasMissing,
  LAST_UPDATE_DATE
) VALUES ( 
  source.SourceSystem,
  source.ProjMarketCodeSourceId,
  source.ProjectId,
  source.MarketCodeId,
  source.Weight,
  source.WasMissing,
  source.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source 
THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: Please include rdbms. Have you try `analyze` / `explain` that query?

Comment: Have you try checking the index?

Comment: `Merge` has a very large overhead, and is very noticeable when you attempt to merge a larger number of records.  I would suggest splitting the million records you're trying to merge into smaller batches.

Comment: I would echo @Siyual's suggestion and additionally suggest doing separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements.  or look at ETL tools like SSIS.